# Estimation of Missing Observations

Tags: time-series

I have a data monthly as well as daily data of no of patients and I want to employ time series model .How can I estimate missing counts.Any one would please guide me

Comment: Hello, Taimoor, and welcome to the site!  It would be easier to answer your question if you could add some more detail to it, for example (but not limited to) what you are trying to estimate, why you want to use a time series model, what you have tried so far, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to estimate the missing data using some other data that you might have collected which has some form of relation with the data that you want to estimate. If there is no other data whatsoever, then you would want to look at some kind of autocorrelation kind of a structure so that you can predict the current value based on some of the previous ones. If there is no such information too, but you can assume the data to be from a particular distribution then use the mean to replace missing data. if no distribution can be assumed, use the median to replace the missing data.

Comment: Using (deterministic) interpolation of some kind (linear, cubic spline, piecewise cubic Hermite, etc.) surely beats use of mean or median when both are possible. Note that @htrahdis' sequence is a sequence from not too bad to fairly lousy methods!

Comment: I politely disagree. The problem is to apply time series methods after filling in the missing data. All the methods you mention add additional properties which might alter the temporal behavior of the original series, so please understand the question first.

Comment: I do think I understand the question too. In turn I point that (a) replacing missings with mean or median are also interpolation methods, but they use less of the available information than the alternatives mentioned (b) using means or medians alone changes _more_ of the properties of the time series as they inevitably reduce its variability. Only replacing missing data with the same data found somehow guarantees no loss of information.

Comment: you are clearly saying that the methods you suggest can be applied after making some additional assumptions which are clearly not given. also a mean and median is something which general time series will have. the properties which your methods will add may eventually not even be part of the actual process. mean and median are unconditional properties whereas interpolation techniques you have mentioned will add conditional properties to data. they will have to be first tested with parts of data which are complete. but in absence of that, they should not be used IMHO.

Comment: Interpolation within blocks of missing values implies that nearby values are better for predictions than whatever else might be used. I am happy to spell out that assumption as it appears not to be evident. Otherwise I can't make sense of your objection, as interpolation is intermediate in character between the methods you suggest, at best using dependence structure if you can and at worst using mean or median. Using mean or median as a general rule will be a poor method if trend or periodicity is evident. I am just filling in a gap in your recommendations. Every method has to be tested.

Comment: I objected because you have said that my suggestions are not too bad to too lousy and the ones that you have suggested are at best more specific than general. they are not wrong. its just that when using time series methods, they might not be as general as they are in other modeling procedures. apart from these, i do not have anything against your suggestions. thanks for them.

Comment: There is _no_ really good method of imputing missing data and it's no criticism of you or anyone else to underline that. You are suggesting some methods and that's fine in general and I added to your suggestions. BTW, I don't quite go with if you know the distribution, use the mean; otherwise use the median: I can imagine cases in which you might have a good idea of the distribution but prefer medians to means.

Comment: @ htrahdis ,you are saying that replace mean or median to replace missing data but i think they will alter the behaviour of time series data.I have red few articles but I am not able to understand,one of them is: A missing values imputation method for time series data:an efficient method to investigate the health effects of sulphur dioxide levels.Please read this.

Comment: give more details about your data and the problem, i would love to help you out. i gave a general answer and it did not satisfy you, lets get some more specifics.

Comment: Thank you very much. I mean to say that I have daily count  of Diabetic patients from a hospital which  remain closed in holidays other than sundays,so counts for holidays  are missing.Besides due to poor data management few other counts  are also missing.Now this is a times series of counts with missing data.Firstly, I want to impute missing values and then to estimate ARIMA  and discrete time series  model.

Comment: This is a tough one because the data is missing for a special day which could have different dynamics from all other days. Try and look at it from what happens on a Sunday although even that will not be perfect. Also look at it from the point of view of what happens just before and after the holiday but please do not use interpolation at all. you will have to make assumptions here of some kind specific to the domain.

Comment: Yes,but there are certain techniques like EM Algorithm which can be employed to impute missing values.But problem is this that I am not able to understand it.

Comment: all those methods are good if you assume that the data generating process for the missing data is the same as the rest of the data points, but here its not an easy assumption to make.